# Galois of successive polynomials in the series expansion $e^x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}$.

Tags: calculus, algebraic-number-theory

I read in a French paper an assertion without proof that I had not known before and that really catches my attention:

*The Galois group over $\mathbb{Q}$ of the equation $1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+….+\frac{x^n}{n!}=0$  is either the alternating group An when 4 divides n, or the symmetric group Sn when 4 does not divide n.*

I want to have proof of this noteworthy result and try to find where. For now, let me know if for each $ n\geq2$ this polynomial is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ which seems not obvious. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is originally a theorem by Schur from 1930. An alternate proof using Newton polygons is available here: [Robert Coleman, On the Galois Groups of the exponential Taylor polynomials, L'Enseignement Mathematique, v 33 (1987) pp 183-189](http://people.math.gatech.edu/~mbaker/pdf/Coleman_GaloisNewton.pdf). For a nice exposition see [Matt Baker's Math Blog](https://mattbakerblog.wordpress.com/2014/05/02/newton-polygons-and-galois-groups/).

Comment: Thank you very much! Is there also the proof of irreducibility?

Comment: @LuisGomezSanchez: Yes, there is.

Comment: Extraordinary Baker's blog. Very grateful for your help.
I wrote to Baker about strong reasons why I loved his article and especially its link "Effective Chabauty".